# Getting started with Festival (on iphone)

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, festival

I'd like to use Festival in an iPhone app. Is this possible, considering the way Festival generates and then plays back audio files? Can I pass Festival an audio file directly from itself to play back? or is there a different way to read  things?

Is there another Text-to-speech engine for C/C++ to use with iphone?

EDIT: Free is better.

EDIT: Which files are absolutely necessary to include into my project what are the core methods of Festival? I looked at the example and the `src` but I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Acapela TTS engine.  It's license is not free however: http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-for-iphone-multilingual-speech-synthesis-available-for-iphone-applications--2028-speech-synthesis.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks good, but I guess I need to wait and see what they want to charge me.